# Pull post meta with post_query?

Tags: wp-query, query, post-meta

I'm building a custom index loop that just uses query_posts at the moment.

The issue is that inside The Loop, I have to then query for the post meta data (with get_post_meta), which I believe has to query the DB each time it's called.  Is there any way I can pull the meta data with the query_posts? I'd need most if not all of the meta data stored for each post.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you're a mistaken on a couple of points here.

## 1. Don't use `query_posts()`

This function is meant for *modifying* an existing query, not performing a standalone query.  You should either use `get_posts()` or a new instance of the `WP_Query()` class to perform your query for the custom loop.

Here's some further reading on `query_posts()`:

- [Querying Posts Without query_posts()](http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/)
- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/46)

## 2. `get_post_meta()` doesn't hit the DB repeatedly

When you do run a post query, WordPress retrieves not only the post, but also the post meta.  We use a built-in object cache to insulate the database from repeated requests for the same information.  If you're using a caching plugin on top of this, you can also receive the benefits of server-side tools like memcached.

You can read about the object cache [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).  Take a close look at the list of persistent cache plugins at the bottom of the page, not only will they make `get_post_meta()` calls lighter, they'll speed up other elements of the site as well.

Comment: Well perfect, I've never seen much on the caching in Wordpress, and didn't know it caught post meta, that's really good to know.  And I'll swap out query posts too, thanks!